# Composer could not find the config file

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I want to create a laravel project by composer. I try to run this:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel c:/laravel --prefer-dist
```

There is an error which is:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Composer could not find the config file: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
  To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in
   the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

The composer.json file is:

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/laravel": "4.2.0"
    }
}
```

I am using windows 8 and use cygwin.
I also have a proxy on my computer so I set the path of HTTP_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI and HTTPS_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI to 0 and false

Any idea?

Answer (score 16):

**Delete** the environment variable **composer**. And It will work.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution like this:

```
COMPOSER=composer.json composer create-project laravel/laravel c:/laravel --prefer-dist
```

and it works!

Answer (score 1):

See: [Composer on Windows 7 (x64): issue #1720](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1720)

The link above recommends that you delete the environment variable `COMPOSER`.

I have tried, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the environment variable **composer**. Worked for me.

Comment: Sorry for repeating this answer. I could not upvote Iram's answer as I am new and dont have enough reputation credit.

Answer (score 0):

did you put your composer.json under c:/Laravel? if yes
in your cmd:

```
C:\> cd Laravel

C:\Laravel> composer create-project laravel/laravel project-name --prefer-dist
```

Comment: I put that in the C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin and I changed the directory to this path. Like: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin> composer create-project laravel/laravel projectname --prefer-dist

Comment: I also have a proxy which I set the path of HTTP_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI and HTTPS_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI to 0 and false

Comment: did it work? all you need to do was to go to that folder where you put your composer.json and run composer there.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note to everybody make sure to restart your doc command prompt windows after you remove the env by going to start type env press on Environmental, under system look for composer and remove the line. I spent an hour till i realized that i needed to restart the dam command window.

Answer (score 0):

Note: As suggested above **remove Environment variables**, if you remove the environment variable you *may not be able to run the composer command successfully*, depending on how many times composer is defined in your variables.

as for me I had different composer environment variables from continuous tweaking, I had to delete them all, I decided to re-install composer using the windows installer and ticked the box that says install as developer (without including uninstall files), the I checked to see where it would install it and it showed my C:\ directory, so I accepted.
After successful install I opened new git bash in my project directory, and ran the

```
composer install
```

command. and it was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and it worked.

You have a COMPOSER environment variable defined and set to `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin`.

You should unset/delete that env var.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 10.
I was trying to create a new project in VS Code in the bash terminal (composer create-project roots/bedrock) but I was getting an error.

1. The folder where the new project should be created should be empty.
2. Opened the desired directory in Windows, launched the "bash" command window in this folder and was able to create the project.

The error only appeared in VS Code in the bash terminal.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldnt erase the environment variable to work.
If the variable name was composer, you only must change the name to composerpath.
It's work to me.