# Error installing laravel using composer

Tags: laravel, project, composer-php, installation

I have followed a tutorial on Tuts plus called "Getting started with laravel 4". I have intalled cygwin and composer which works fine. When i try installing laravel using the following command:

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel
```

i get the following message:

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v4.2.0)
Downloading: 100%

Created project in laravel


[InvalidArgumentException]
Composer could not find the config file: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the 
http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

I have tried looking at the Getting Started section but I am not sure what this file should contain in a laravel project?

Answer (score 2):

Go to

control panel > search for system > view advance system setting > environment variables > under system variable, select composer and delete it > ok> ok.

I think this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You must not create `laravel` project on your own.

You should go to directory in which you want `laravel` directory to be created (and `laravel` directory must not exist) and now you should run:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel
```

`laravel` directory will be created automatically

Comment: In cygwin I have navigated to /cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs which is where i run: composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel. This also creates the laravel directory but when i navigate to: http://localhost/laravel/public/ there is errors so i think the installation went wrong

Comment: @user3170354 And it should work without a problem if you have no `laravel` directory inside `/cygdrive/c/xampp/htdocs`/ If you have you should remove it and run the command once again. It should work. If it's not, probably there is some problem with your installation

Comment: I have also tried that multiple times. However every time this produces the following errors.


Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this:

COMPOSER=composer.json composer create-project laravel/laravel c:/laravel --prefer-dist

founded on - [Composer could not find the config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986258/composer-could-not-find-the-config-file/25986667#25986667).

It works for me!