# Laravel setup project file fails

Tags: php, laravel

I've searched many answers to this problem, and a alternative solution to this project to still get what I try to achieve, but I want to know why it is not working the 'regular' way, and if it is possible to fix it somehow. I checked out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986258/composer-could-not-find-the-config-file) where I found my alternative solution.

I installed laravel and I'm trying to create a project with laravel. However, when I run this command

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel cms
```

I get the following error: `[InvalidArgumentException] - Composer could not find the config file`

I followed all installation settings via a tutorial, created the composer enviroment variable, so those settings should be correct. Does somebody know why this is not working and how I might be able to fix this?

Edit: To clarify, as Joe commented, composer commands do work.

Comment: Does any other composer command work? try a    composer self-update

Comment: What do you get when running `composer diag` ?

Comment: Try the following: Create a 'cms' folder. CD to that folder and do a `composer init` then try a `composer create-project laravel/laravel .` (note the .)

Comment: Thanks for thinking with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, run the following command:

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

then, add `~/.composer/vendor/bin to your PATH.` this way your system knows where the laravel installer is.
When this is done, you can simple use the following command to make a new project:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

I had this problem myself since i was used to use composer to init a laravel project. However, after setting up this installer, i honestly love it. It has a bunch of neat options you can use ;-)

For more info, look [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation)