# Laravel setup issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am new in laravel development,actually i tried to setup laravel in my local environment of windows.
I installed composer in my C:// drive, created environment variable for composer, but when I `C:\xampp\htdocs>composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel_new`  run this command in htdocs it shows error like:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
> Composer could not find the config file: C:\composer
> To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as
> described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting S     tarted"
> section

also when I tried php artisan serve

`C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_new>php artisan serve`

> PHP Warning:
> require(C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_new/vendor/autoload.php): Failed to
> open stream: No such file or directory in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_new\artisan on line 18
> Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_new/vendor/autoload.php):
> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_new\artisan on line 18
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_new/vendor/autoload.php'
> (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_new\artisan:18
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}                                                                                                                 thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_new\artisan on line 18
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_new/vendor/autoload.php'
> (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_new\artisan:18
> Stack trace:
> #0 {main}                                                                                                                 thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel_new\artisan on line 18

it shows error like above.
What should I do to complete my setup?

Comment: Check composer installed or not  ? Check by `terminal` using command  `composer` ?

Comment: yes composer installed properly i checked

Comment: I think your `composer` install is not properly. Uninstall then install composer again

Comment: The error message of composer says that it can not find your `composer.json` file. Could you check if the laravel installer has created one for you? If so, run `composer install` in your project path. If that does not fail, php atrisan should work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27638890/8607640 see this answer. Probably this will help you

Comment: it tried composer install in  my file path but haven't worked

Comment: If you're new to Laravel and other tools it depends on, my advice is to Google for the "Laragon" project if you want pure Windows environment, but (IMHO) the best is "Laradock.io" if you're ok with WSL+Docker. With that you'll have a container named "workspace" with all the tools you need for a Laravel project. I'm using it for years and it's a life saver. Trust me...

Comment: actually i resolved the error and why i am facing this errors because of my anti virus which doesn't allow to install all dependencies i just uninstall that this errors are resolved but last error i am getting that "Mcrypt PHP extension required." i insatlled php_mcrypt.dll and paste that file in php.ini still facing that error. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you did something wrong when you install your xampp,composer,so what you have to do is uninstall xampp and install last version (add php to your path environment) and uninstall your composer and download last version and install it globally